# Row-wise operations with mutate_at

Tags: r, dplyr, rowwise

Using `dplyr`, is there a way to selectively mutate columns by row without using `rowwise()`?

For example, given input below, I want to replace negative numbers with zeroes in columns prefixed with "pre_":

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(-5, 3, 4, 5), b=4:1, pre_c=c(-1, -5, 3, 10), pre_d=c(-6, 5, -12, 0))
#    a b pre_c pre_d
# 1 -5 4    -1    -6
# 2  3 3    -5     5
# 3  4 2     3   -12
# 4  5 1    10     0
```

My desired output is:

```
#    a b pre_c pre_d
# 1 -5 4     0     0
# 2  3 3     0     5
# 3  4 2     3     0
# 4  5 1    10     0
```

This can be acheived with `rowwise()` and `mutate_at()`:

```
df %>% 
   rowwise() %>% 
   mutate_at(vars(starts_with("pre_")), funs(max(0, .)))
```

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

You could use `pmax` (or `replace`) without `rowwise`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("pre_")), list(~pmax(0, .)))
   a b pre_c pre_d
1 -5 4     0     0
2  3 3     0     5
3  4 2     3     0
4  5 1    10     0
```

Using `base R`

```
df[startsWith(names(df), "pre_")][df[startsWith(names(df), "pre_")] < 0] <- 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
df %>%
 mutate_at(vars(starts_with("pre_")), list(~ (. > 0) * .))

   a b pre_c pre_d
1 -5 4     0     0
2  3 3     0     5
3  4 2     3     0
4  5 1    10     0
```